# Anonymous access to resource with Apache CXF and oAuth2

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf

I have currently converted my resteasy project to Apache CXF and configured my project to use OAuth2. Now at the moment if the client is not authenticated all methods return `401 Unauthorized`.

Now I have several methods which should not require any authentication and I was wondering if there is an existing annotation to allow all requests to pass-through.

For example if I have the following service and I want to allow anyone to access `/manage/frontpage` (This will be a status page for the service).

```
@Path("manage")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
public class ManageService {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger( ManageService.class );

    @GET("frontpage")
    @PermitAll
    public String frontpage() {
        return "Management Service Status";
    }
}
```

I have tried the @PermitAll annotation but that doesn't seem to change anything. I understand that I can create a filter class and manually allow the request, but I am wondering if there isn't already such a filter built-in?